# Higher-Order Function Scheme: Incrementing via Returned Value

Tags: function, syntax, parameters, lambda, scheme

I'm having issues with some functionality in Scheme

So in this book i'm learning about Scheme i've come across this problem that I don't quite grasp yet.

It's asking me to create a high order function that does this:

```
(display ((incrementn 4) 2))
6
```

I've been stuck on this for a couple of hours and still seem to have not understood the fundamentals. So i'm turning to you all in hopes I can get some better understanding on this functional call.

So the way I understand it so far is that when we define a function like so:

```
(define (increment n) ______)
```

The blank spaces obviously represent my following manipulation of the arguments given. What i don't seem to understand is how the high order function returns the outside argument (of the increment function) and injects it into the defined function(which is (incrementn 3) )

I understand fully that 3 is the initial value (integer) that we increment n times (n being the argument passed outside of the ((incrementn n) x) ) that we *increment n by 1 x times*

The question i'm asking you simply is that given x being an unbound variable (right?) how do I return that integer and increment n by 1 that many times? What is the syntax for this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the point to understand here is that after we call `incrementn` with `3` as the initial argument it will return a *function*, and that afterwards `2` is passed as an argument to that function. This is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), and the solution is straightforward after you grasp the concept at play here:

```
(define (incrementn n)
  (lambda (x)
    (+ n x)))
```

As you can see, the call to `incrementn` *captures* the value of the `n` parameter in the returned `lambda`, and when we call it passing `x`, `n` is there to be used in the expressions in the body of the `lambda`. Now, it works as expected:

```
((incrementn 4) 2)
=> 6

((incrementn -1) 3)
=> 2
```

Comment: So incrementn in this instance isn't only taking in n, it is also taking in (lambda (x)) as well even though it's outside of definition of incrementn? EDIT: You answered in the edit, thank you

Comment: Also, it's incrementing, so changing from * to + would be correct because ((incrementn -1) 3) = 2. (it's what he had as another example)

Comment: @S.Shaw ok, got it - it's fixed now :)